# Bootstrap 4 dropdown se oculta detras de la pagina, necesito que este encima de toda la tabla

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

```css
:root {
  --colorTextoClaro: #999999;
  --colorTexto: #373838;
  --colorTextoOscuro: #5B5B5B;
  --verdePrincipal: #009A3C;
  --fondoGrisClaro: #F5F4F4;
  --fondoSwt: #FCFCFC;
  --bordeInputs: #C4C4C4;
  --naranjaLogo: #F19B0A;
  --naranjaStatus: #F39200;
  --rojoStatus: #da251c;
  --grisFooter: #6D777A;
  --hrColor: #E0E0E0;
  --grisSexto: #8A8C8E;
  --bgComentarios: #FAFAFA;
  --colorDateCommet: #CFCECE;
  --myselfMsg: #CAFFAA;
  --verdeStatusBar: #4FB725;
  --verdeSubMenu: rgba(3, 137, 58, 0.98);
  --hoverRows: #e0f1e7;
  --verdeActive: #019A40;
  --fondoToolTip: #FFFDFD;
  --borderToolTip: #EAEAEA;
}

a {
  color: var(--verdePrincipal);
}

body {
  color: var(--colorTexto);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px;
}

a:hover {
 color: var(--verdePrincipal) !important;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
.wm-100 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.mb-18 {
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}
.m-75 {
  padding-left: 75px !important;
}
.sp {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.sm {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.row_wfl_ppal {
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow-x: auto;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      background: #FFFFFF;
      border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      border-radius: 10px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal::-webkit-scrollbar {
      height: 5px;
      margin: 0px 10px;
      background-color: #F5F5F5;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      background-color: #F5F5F5;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: #b3b3b3;
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .ppal_table .item_column,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: -4px;
      vertical-align: top;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .ppal_table .item_column:first-child,
  .row_wfl_ppal .ppal_table .item_column:last-child,
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column.ic_ddwn,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column:first-child,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column.ic_ddwn,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column:first-child,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column.ic_ddwn {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 4%;
      flex: 0 0 4%;
      max-width: 4%;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead {
      height: 76px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column {
      border-bottom: 2px solid var(--hrColor);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody {
      border-bottom: 1px solid var(--hrColor);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody:last-child {
      border-bottom: 0;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column,
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column {
      color: var(--colorTextoClaro);
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 21px;
      height: 100%;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column {
      height: 75px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .intern_clp_link,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column .intern_clp_link {
      color: var(--verdePrincipal);
      position: absolute;
      left: -45px;
      top: 24px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .intern_clp_link span,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column .intern_clp_link span {
      font-size: 1.4em;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column .item .sort {
      color: var(--colorTextoClaro);
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 21px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column .item .sort:hover span {
      color: var(--verdePrincipal);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_colmumn_name,
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_colmumn_name,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_colmumn_name,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_colmumn_name {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 23.2%;
      flex: 0 0 23.2%;
      max-width: 23.2%;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_colmumn_type,
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_colmumn_type,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_colmumn_type,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_colmumn_type {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 10.5%;
      flex: 0 0 10.5%;
      max-width: 10.5%;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column .item,
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .item,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column .item,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column .item {
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      white-space: normal;
      word-break: break-word;
      display: flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
      align-items: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column .item,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column .item {
      opacity: .75;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .btn_action_fixed .item,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .btn_action_fixed .item {
      opacity: 1;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column .sort span {
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-right: 2px;
      color: var(--colorTextoClaro);
      font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .item .icon_box {
      background-color: var(--verdePrincipal);
      border-radius: 22px;
      height: 22px;
      width: 22px;
      display: flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
      align-items: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .item .icon_box span {
      color: white;
      font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody.filaAbierta {
      position: relative;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody.filaAbierta .item_column {
      border-bottom: 1px solid var(--hrColor);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .second_table {
      position: relative;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .second_table:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 74px;
      height: 1px;
      background-color: var(--hrColor);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table {
      border-bottom: 1px solid var(--hrColor);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table:last-child {
      border-bottom: 0;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column:nth-child(2),
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column:nth-child(3) {
      padding-left: 43px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column:nth-child(2) .item,
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column:nth-child(3) .item,
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column:nth-child(2) .item,
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column:nth-child(3) .item {
      justify-content: flex-start;
      -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .resp_photo {
      display: block;
      margin: 0px 0px 8px;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .resp_photo img {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-height: 33px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .info_respo {
      color: #999999;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 12px;
      display: block;
      line-height: 14px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column.btn_action_fixed a [class^="icon-"],
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column.btn_action_fixed a [class*=" icon-"] {
      font-size: 1em;
      margin-right: 0px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .responsable {
      flex-direction: column;
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .status {
      font-size: 1.2em;
      margin-right: 6px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .cerrado {
      border-radius: 12px;
      border-right-color: white;
      border-top-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
      border-bottom-color: white;
      border-left-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
      border-width: 8px;
      border-style: solid;
      height: 0px;
      margin-right: 6px;
      position: relative;
      width: 0px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .cerrado:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -8px;
      left: -8px;
      right: 0px;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid var(--verdeStatusBar);
      margin: auto;
      border-radius: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .pendiente {
      border-radius: 12px;
      border-right-color: --colorTextoClaro;
      border-top-color: var(--colorTextoClaro);
      border-bottom-color: --colorTextoClaro;
      border-left-color: var(--colorTextoClaro);
      border-width: 8px;
      border-style: solid;
      height: 0px;
      margin-right: 6px;
      position: relative;
      width: 0px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .pendiente:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -8px;
      left: -8px;
      right: 0px;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid var(--colorTextoClaro);
      margin: auto;
      border-radius: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .rechazado {
      border-radius: 12px;
      border-right-color: var(--rojoStatus);
      border-top-color: var(--rojoStatus);
      border-bottom-color: var(--rojoStatus);
      border-left-color: var(--rojoStatus);
      border-width: 8px;
      border-style: solid;
      height: 0px;
      margin-right: 6px;
      position: relative;
      width: 0px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .rechazado:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -8px;
      left: -8px;
      right: 0px;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid var(--rojoStatus);
      margin: auto;
      border-radius: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .finalizado {
      border-radius: 12px;
      border-right-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
      border-top-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
      border-bottom-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
      border-left-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
      border-width: 8px;
      border-style: solid;
      height: 0px;
      margin-right: 6px;
      position: relative;
      width: 0px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .finalizado:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -8px;
      left: -8px;
      right: 0px;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid var(--verdeStatusBar);
      margin: auto;
      border-radius: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .en_proceso {
      border-radius: 12px;
      border-right-color: var(--naranjaStatus);
      border-top-color: var(--naranjaStatus);
      border-bottom-color: var(--naranjaStatus);
      border-left-color: var(--naranjaStatus);
      border-width: 8px;
      border-style: solid;
      height: 0px;
      margin-right: 6px;
      position: relative;
      width: 0px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .en_proceso:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -8px;
      left: -8px;
      right: 0px;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid var(--naranjaStatus);
      margin: auto;
      border-radius: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .active {
      color: var(--verdePrincipal);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .item .dropdown-menu {
      right: 0px;
      transform: none !important;
      will-change: initial !important;
      top: 45px !important;
      left: auto !important;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table {
      position: relative
  }
  .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: white;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .btn_action_fixed,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .btn_action_fixed,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .btn_action_fixed {
      background-color: white;
      right: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 4%;
      flex: 0 0 4%;
      max-width: 4%;
      opacity: 1;
      position: sticky;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: -moz-sticky;
      position: -o-sticky;
      position: -ms-sticky;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .btn_action_fixed .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item span,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .btn_action_fixed .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item span,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .btn_action_fixed .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item span {
      margin-right: 16px !important;
  }

  .icon_box {
    color: white;
  }

  .icon_box:hover {
    color: white !important;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid sp" style="min-width: 1440px;">
    <div class="row sm flex-nowrap flex-column row_wfl_ppal">
        <div class="ppal_table div_thead">
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#" class="sort" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="icon-icon_arrow-down2"></span> Código
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ascendente</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Descendente</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 item_column item_colmumn_name">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#" class="sort" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="icon-icon_arrow-down2"></span> Nombre del workflow
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ascendente</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Descendente</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">Tracking</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">Tracking</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">Fecha de inicio</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">Fecha de fin</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">Estado</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 item_column">
                <div class="item">Responsable</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column item_colmumn_type">
                <div class="item">Tipo</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTableAddColumn">
                        +
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ppal_table div_tbody">
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">
                    <a class="icon_box collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#submenu1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="submenu1">
                        >
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">WF0025</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 item_column item_colmumn_name">
                <div class="item">Procedimiento horas extras</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">0 de 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">0 de 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">25/03/2020</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">10/01/2020</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">
                    <span class="status cerrado"></span> Cerrado
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 item_column">
                <div class="item responsable">
                    <figure class="resp_photo"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS0Pca271LUiEyu-Np7IYtmgUm5MEhYutLik4loBfq0wwap4Uxo&s" alt="user1" class="img-fluid rounded-circle"></figure>
                    <p class="mb-0 info_respo">Ayer a las 3:20 pm</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column item_colmumn_type">
                <div class="item">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column btn_action_fixed ic_ddwn">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        ...
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarWorkflow">
                            <span class="icon-icon_pencil"></span> Editar
                        </a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                            <span class="icon-icon_trash-light"></span> Eliminar
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="break"></div>
            <div class="second_table w-100 collapse" id="submenu1">
                <div class="col-1 item_column">
                    <div class="item">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 item_column">
                    <div class="item">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 item_column item_colmumn_name">
                    <div class="item">
                        <a class="intern_clp_link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#thirdMenu1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdMenu1">
                            >
                        </a>
                        Etapa 1
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 item_column">
                    <div class="item">0 de 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 item_column">
                    <div class="item">
                        Card4
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 item_column">
                    <div class="item">
                        Card5
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 item_column">
                    <div class="item">
                        Card6
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 item_column">
                    <div class="item">
                        Card7
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 item_column">
                    <div class="item">
                        Card8
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 item_column item_colmumn_type">
                    <div class="item">
                        Card9
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 item_column btn_action_fixed ic_ddwn">
                    <div class="item">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            ...
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarWorkflow">
                                <span class="icon-icon_pencil"></span> Editar
                            </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                <span class="icon-icon_trash-light"></span> Eliminar
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="third_table w-100 collapse multi-collapse" id="thirdMenu1">
                    <div class="col-1 item_column"> 
                        <div class="item">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1 item_column"> 
                        <div class="item">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 item_column item_colmumn_name">
                        <div class="item">
                            Card3
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1 item_column">
                        <div class="item">0 de 2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1 item_column">
                        <div class="item">
                            Card4
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1 item_column">
                        <div class="item">
                            Card5
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1 item_column">
                        <div class="item">
                            Card6
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1 item_column">
                        <div class="item">
                            Card7
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 item_column">
                        <div class="item">
                            Card7
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1 item_column item_colmumn_type">
                        <div class="item">
                            Card8
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1 item_column btn_action_fixed ic_ddwn">
                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                ...
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarWorkflow">
                                    <span class="icon-icon_pencil"></span> Editar
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                    <span class="icon-icon_trash-light"></span> Eliminar
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

En primer lugar, es una tabla dinámica hecha con divs, a su vez, se puede desplazar horizontalmente, y también cada fila de la tabla tiene un collapse de bootstrap para mostrar otras filas dentro.. Necesito el menú desplegable como un z-index 9999, es decir, que el dropdown se muestre por encima de todos los elementos que incluyen la tabla, pero no puedo hacerlo flotante, por qué cada menú desplegable debe ir debajo del botón de acción, los tres puntos.

Aca el codigo en CODEPLY -> https://www.codeply.com/p/WdmSpQTJcr

[image: aca los puntos a considerar]

Algo como esto seria lo q quiero como resultado:

[image: resultado requerido]

---

[image: captura de lo que debe tener la solucion]

estos 3 elementos son requisito, 1.- el scroll horizontal por que la tabla puede tener N cantidad de columnas, 2.- el boton de acciones (los 3 puntos) deben estar fijos a la derecha para que con todo el scroll horizontal se mantenga visible y 3.- el collapse en cada elemento de la tabla, por q cada workflow tiene etapas y actividades relacionadas.

Comment: Necesariamente debe ser una tabla de divs?

Comment: si claro.. me la pidieron asi, sino fuese utilizado datatables o algo parecido..

Comment: Has pensado en agregar un `padding-bottom` al `row_wfl_ppal` de 50px? eso te da suficiente margen para que se muestre el dropdown

Comment: no no sirve.. es una tabla van a haber por vista 7 row_wfl_ppal  y no puede tener sino ese tamaño, es decir, el dropdown debe ser flotante, estar por encima de todo.. creo q voy a tener que ver como lo aplico con JS